# Unity-Ubuntu 16.04 dock and panel disappeared

Tags: unity, system-settings, dock, gpu-driver

This happened somewhere when I switched to `using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs...` in the Additional Drivers Settings, or uninstalled a system app called ibus. I cannot revert back now, since both the Dock and the Panel are gone, and I'm unable to find System Settings as well. It almost feels like I can't do anything now, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't give me a Terminal. Anyone who knows what was wrong here? Please help me out.

P.S. I have a AMD GPU driver. Previously,  the setting under additional drivers was something like `do not use the device`.

Comment: IMHO, anything that has to do with low level stuff like BIOS and CPU microcode should not be messed with :)

Comment: @AndroidDev one thing I'm sure of is that neither of the two were tweaked, I simply changed the Ubuntu system settings through its GUI though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when Ubuntu Unity plugin is disabled in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Press ctrl+alt+f1 and enter your login credentials. Then run

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager unity-desktop unity
```

and

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
```

Now go back to desktop by pressing ctrl+alt+f7 (or ctrl+alt+f8 if f7 doesn't work). CompizConfig Settings Manager should be there.

From ccsm, find Ubuntu Unity Plugin and enable it if it's disabled.

Finally you need to restart your computer, you can do it from the GUI or typing `sudo reboot` to any terminal.